# How to find the grid line from extracted points in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, numerical-methods

I am trying to extract the horizontal / vertical lines from (incomplete) grid points. Here is simplified example:

```
% grid(): 2D matrix containing actual grid points, which are unknown
% points(): 1D matrix containing found grid points, which are incomplete
% assuming 5X5 grid

points = [grid(1,1);grid(1,2);grid(1,3);grid(1,4);
          grid(2,1);grid(2,3);grid(2,4);grid(2,5);
          grid(3,1);grid(3,2);grid(3,3);grid(3,4);grid(3,5);
          grid(4,1);grid(4,2);grid(4,3);grid(4,4);grid(3,5);
          grid(5,1);grid(5,2);grid(5,4);grid(5,5)];
```

The result what I expect is:

- Finding the line equations of each column & row by regression. In this case, the set contains 5 horizontal and 5 vertical equations: For example,  *param_row(5,2)* and *param_column(5,2)* would be the parameter set for each 1D line (*y=**a**x+**b***)
- Complete grid() matrix by calculating the cross point between horizontal and vertical equations. I this case, *grid(1,5);grid(2,2);grid(5.3)* should be obtained

Thanks for help.

---

**EDIT**:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_UjxbISeZDrZDlWaV9ZaXVtbmc/view?usp=sharing

Here is the (binary) grid image what I should handle (I couldn't post image on the main text). The position of ON pixels are stored at `point()`. In this image, `grid()` are the set of cross points among the fitted horizontal / vertical lines. So, *"Complete grid() matrix"* means finding missed points on the image.

Comment: So `grid(1,5);grid(2,2);grid(5.3)` are `NaN`? You want to extrapolate to those unknown points? Are the values on `grid` a linear function? Is there noise present?

Comment: @knedlsepp `grid()` is virtual data set, so I must estimate these values. Also it contains the noise; that's the reason why I try regression.

Comment: What do you mean by virtual data set? Care giving us some example data?

Comment: @knedlsepp https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_UjxbISeZDrZDlWaV9ZaXVtbmc/view?usp=sharing Here is the (binary) grid image what I should handle (I couldn't post image on the main text). The position of ON pixels are stored at `point()`. In this image, `grid()` are the set of cross points among the fitted horizontal / vertical lines. So, *"Complete grid() matrix"* means finding missed points on the image.

Comment: This is a lot different from your original question! If you want this, better ask it directly! Will these grid points ever be rotated?

Comment: Also: How can 2D-positions be stored in the single matrix `point`?

Comment: @knedlsepp As you see on the image, the points are initially bit rotated, however the original image would never be changed. That's why I thought about the regression.

Comment: The data structures you are describing don't match the problem.

Comment: @knedlsepp I stored the position matrix by the code like: `[point(:,1) point(:,2)] = find(BW==1);`. So it contains position data only, not about the row or column information.

Comment: Yes, But you say *1D matrix containing found grid points*

Comment: I would suggest to you that you delete this first `find` step you have done from your question and ask directly: Given an image like you got, blablabla.

Comment: @knedlsepp That's my fault. I wrote *1D* meaning *lack of the row or column information*.

Comment: @knedlsepp I understand. I will re-write the question. Thanks for advice.

Comment: In the meantime: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476367/grid-detection-in-matlab) might be an interesting read.

Comment: You should probably also explain how the images you are trying to process differ/are the same. Like: Will the spacing of the points always be uniform? Will the grid size always be 13x14? Will the white points in the image always be single pixels?